# How to set or get the NetworkAddress key from the registry

Tags: c#, registrykey

I want to read and modify the registry key value of my NetworkAddress. Its path in the registry is:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0011

Inside that path there is a key named NetworkAddress. How do I read and modify this key?

Here is what I have tried:

```
 RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0011",true);
       MessageBox.Show((string) myKey.GetValue("NetworkAddress"));
       myKey.SetValue("NetworkAddress", "002408B2A2D2", RegistryValueKind.String);
```

I have tried this code and it is giving me this exception: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** How do I solve this issue? Please help me and thank you.

Comment: You are getting the exception because the factory method couldn't find the key at the specified location and returned `null`.

Comment: yes I know but the key is existing at that location and to ensure that I am at the right path I copy the destination from the registry directly
I think it is a permission issue?

Comment: If you have insufficient permissions to access a registry key then a `System.Security.Security` exception will be thrown. I think you need elevated privileges to write to the `LOCAL_MACHINE` key hive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the exception because the factory method couldn't find the sub key at the specified location and returned `null`.

Despite your sub key address being perfectly valid, because you are using `Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey` you are essentially specifying `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the sub key address twice. The solution is to change your sub-key path to:

> SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0011

You may also want to consider a more robust approach:

```
using (RegistryKey myKey =
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
        @"SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0011", true))
{
    if (myKey != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((string) myKey.GetValue("NetworkAddress"));
        myKey.SetValue("NetworkAddress", "002408B2A2D2", RegistryValueKind.String);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C# is quite a rich language, so this is a lot easier to do without the registry

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;

var local = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces().Where(i => i.Name == "Local Area Connection").FirstOrDefault();
var stringAddress = local.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[0].Address.ToString();
var ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(address);
```